# socket.timeout : The read operation timed out? Gmail API

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I have been receiving the following error:

```html
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

It happens during various Gmail API requests, such as the following.

```html
response = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=threadID, fields='messages(id)').execute()
```

Or

```html
response = service.users().messages().list(userId=userID, labelIds=labelList, pageToken=page_token, maxResults=500, fields="messages(id),nextPageToken").execute()
```

Or

```html
att = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId=userID, messageId=messageID, id=att_id).execute()
```

I make several various Gmail API requests and these are  just some of many. Most of them I believe eventually throw this error.

I have tried increasing my timeout to 600 seconds. The following is an http object I use for batch requests.

```html
    def build_http(self): 
        """Builds httplib2.Http object 

        Returns: 
        A httplib2.Http object, which is used to make http requests, and which has timeout set by default. 
        To override default timeout call 

            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout_in_sec) 

        before interacting with this method. 
        """ 
        try: 
            #DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT_SEC = 600
            #if socket.getdefaulttimeout() is not None: 
            #    http_timeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout() 
            #else: 
            #    http_timeout = DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT_SEC 

            return httplib2.Http(timeout=600) 
        except: 
            self.GLogger.error("An error was encountered in build_http")
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self.GLogger.exception(tb)
            return False
```

And

```html
socket.setdefaulttimeout(600)
```

It is not apparent why this is occurring. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve these errors? They occur rather frequently.

Here is my function for obtaining Gmail credentials.

```html
def gmailAPIInitialize(self):
try:
    self.waitForInternet()
    self.GLogger.info("Initializing the Gmail API Service")
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    #service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
    self.gmailAPIService  = service
    self.GLogger.info("Successfully initialized the Gmail API Service")
    return True
except:
    self.GLogger.error("An error was encountered while attempting to initialize the Gmail API")
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    self.GLogger.exception(tb)
    return False
```

I am also running two instances of the Gmail API Service. Each of these two instances run this function separately with a different set of variables.
These two instances are performing similar API requests simultaneously. Is this an issue? They are connecting to the same account.

I initially did not think this would be an issue, because I believe it would be expected that there could be several Gmail API instances for an account, such as different Email Apps, Email Clients, etc.

Edit* So I just created two different credentials to the same account. I thought that this might serve to separate the two instances and their fetches.
Edit* socket.timeout errors still occurring.

Edit* Removed the other Gmail API Thread that was performing the same requests to the same account (using different credentials). The socket.timeout error appears to no longer occur.
**Is this not permitted?** I have two threads doing the effectively the same operations (with slight differences), and have assigned two different credentials to these two threads that are processing the same email account.

Comment: Can you provide enough code to reproduce this, including the auth process? Consider taking a look at the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'd consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).